# The footer doesnt stick to the bottom of the webpage but is fixed but not hidden

Tags: html

I have created a style CSS to stick the footer hidden at the bottom however it doesn't so I have to scroll the page down to see the rest of the content in the body. This makes the webpage look squashed

Here is the html

```
      <footer>

<p class='margin' style="font-family:Century;color:black;font-size:10px;text-align:left">Copyright@ Admin@treacle.me.uk. This sight is property of Retro Alpha. Any unauthorised changes will be prosecuted by governmental offences.

    <br>

This sight is linked to the youtube channel of Yoshi24Gaming. Copyright Legal Act 2014</p>

<div id="More links" class='margin' style="font-family:Century;color:black;font-size:10px;text-align:left">Here are the important links to guide you through this website.

    <br>

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/Yoshi24Gaming">Youtube</a> <a href=retropcgaming.html>Gaming</a> <a href=retropcproducts.html>Products</a> <a href=retropcForum.html>Forum</a> <a href=retropchelpandsupport.html>Help &amp; Support></a> <a href=retropcAuthor.html>Author</a> <a href=>Developer<a/> <a href=>Terms &amp; Conditions</a> <a href=>License</div>
```

Here is the style sheet

```
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">

.margin { margin-left:5px;}
.center { margin:auto;width:78%;}
a:link { color:White;text-decoration: none}
a:hover { color:Blue;text-decoration: none}
a:visited { color:Gray;text-decoration: none}
header { background-image:url('headerback.jpg');height:200px;width:100%;top:0;left:0;position:fixed;}
body { padding:10px;padding-bottom:78px;}
footer { background-color:White;height:78px;width:100%;bottom:0;left:0;position:fixed;}
```

I have been using html 5 coding so the div tag around the footer isn't required.

Comment: There are plenty of errors in your html code, check this fiddle, I corrected them :http://jsfiddle.net/5CzCR/2/

Comment: Could you post the html and css code of the content taht is before your footer pls it is important to answer especialy if it is absolutly , fixed positioned or floated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps you.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070513/css-fix-for-footer-to-be-at-page-bottom)

It explains way to have footer stick at bottom using only CSS.